# Why does Ctrl-D (EOF) exit the shell?

Tags: shell, escape-characters

Are you literally "ending a file" by inputting this escape sequence, i.e. is the interactive shell session is seen as a real file stream by the shell, like any other file stream? If so, which file?

Or, is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> signal just a placeholder which means "the user has finished providing input and you may terminate"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516122/how-to-capture-controld-signal

Comment: FYI, in bash you can do `set -o ignoreeof` to change that behavior.

Comment: I had the same problem.
My error was that I accidentally assigned the konsole profile shortcut to "Ctrl+d". Not my proudest moment.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The `^D` character (also known as `\04` or 0x4, [END OF TRANSMISSION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character) in Unicode) is the default value for the `eof` special control character parameter of the terminal or pseudo-terminal driver in the kernel (more precisely of the [`tty` line discipline attached to the serial or pseudo-tty device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120071/22565)). That's the `c_cc[VEOF]` of the `termios` structure passed to the TCSETS/TCGETS `ioctl` one issues to the terminal device to affect the driver behaviour.

The typical command that sends those `ioctls` is the `stty` command.

To retrieve all the parameters:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 58; columns 191; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O;
min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

That `eof` parameter is only relevant when the terminal device is in `icanon` mode.

In that mode, the terminal driver (not the terminal emulator) implements a very simple *line editor*, where you can type <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to erase a character, <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> to erase the whole line... When an application reads from the terminal device, it sees nothing until you press <kbd>Return</kbd> at which point the `read()` returns the full line including the last `LF` character (by default, the terminal driver also translates the `CR` sent by your terminal upon <kbd>Return</kbd> to `LF`).

Now, if you want to send what you typed so far without pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that's where you can enter the `eof` character. Upon receiving that character from the terminal emulator, the terminal driver *submits* the current content of the line, so that the application doing the `read` on it will receive it as is (and it won't include a trailing `LF` character).

Now, if the current line was empty, and provided the application will have fully read the previously entered lines, the `read` will return 0 character.

That signifies *end of file* to the application (when you read from a file, you read until there's nothing more to be read). That's why it's called the `eof` character, because sending it causes the application to see that no more input is available.

Now, modern shells, at their prompt do not set the terminal in `icanon` mode because they implement their own *line editor* which is much more advanced than the terminal driver built-in one. However, in their own *line editor*, to avoid confusing the users, they give the `^D` character (or whatever the terminal's `eof` setting is with some) the same meaning (to signify `eof`).

Comment: I knew once I began reading this comment that it was written by Stephane :)  You, Stephane, are my Bash hero, and I am not being sarcastic.  I'd love to have lunch with you and pick your brain if you're ever in NYC, I'm buying.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal. Thanks. Chances of me going to NYC anytime soon are pretty slim though.

Comment: It's EOT even in 7-Bit ASCII

Comment: Aaahhhh!  -> "Now, if the current line was empty, and provided the application will have fully read the previously entered lines, the `read` will return 0 character. That signifies *end of file* to the application (when you read from a file, you read until there's nothing more to be read). That's why it's called the `eof` character, because sending it causes the application to see that no more input is available." Finally it makes sense of this end-of-file *character* to which actually no codepoint is associated!

Answer (score 12):

CTRL_D is just a signal saying that this is the end of a text stream. You do not end a file with it, you end your input stream by typing it. Also CTRL_D does not stand for any character or byte as you can find out with the tool hexdump:

```
# cat >test.txt
asdf# hexdump -C test.txt 
00000000  61 73 64 66                                       |asdf|
00000004
# ll test.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4 Jan 21 11:55 test.txt
```

Comment: And the reason that it ends the shell is that the shell is basically a process that accepts input and does stuff with it. When you tell it no more input is going to be coming, there's nothing more for the shell to do.

Comment: I realize that the EOF sequence is not contained by, say, a text file, and is generated by the OS to report that there is no more data to read. I think what I am really asking is if the interactive terminal session is seen as a real file stream by the shell, like any other file stream.

Comment: Just edited the original question to clarify.

Comment: yes, the stream that goes to bash is an input stream like any other. CTRL_D signals that the input stream is at its end and bash can quit.

Comment: Should clarify that it is not a signal in the sense of UNIX signal to a process but in the generic sense : "A way to signal"