# Strange ascii from hexdump of text file

Tags: hexdump

I saw this question [Why does Ctrl-D (EOF) exit the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110240/why-does-ctrl-d-eof-exit-the-shell) and wanted to try the example on the second answer.
So i've created a file and used hexdump:

```
federico@home ~ $ cat > test.txt
prova
^C
federico@home ~ $ hexdump test.txt 
0000000 7270 766f 0a61                         
0000006
```

The second row has '6' in the end, and if i try to use http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm to decode from hex to ascii i get a strange letters order.
Why does this happen?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using a little endian CPU, the 16 bit words hexdump is showing are byte swapped.

`6` is the offset of the second dump line which is empty, your file containing only six bytes.

Use `od -c` or `od -t x1` to get the expected order:

```
$ od -c test.txt 
0000000   p   r   o   v   a  \n
0000006
$ od -t x1 test.txt 
0000000 70 72 6f 76 61 0a
0000006
```

Comment: Thanks, but why the 00006 and not 00004?

Comment: Answer updated to explain the 6.