# How to send ^D / EOT character to stdin of a shell process?

Tags: command-line, escape-characters

Suppose I have two shells open, one with PID 1234 and the other - 5678.

I can [clear the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7660837/3701431) and reset of the other shell via `echo $'\033c' > /proc/1234/fd/0` as if `reset` was typed on the prompt of the terminal itself. However, when I do `echo $'\04' > /proc/1234/fd/0` to send EOT character, this doesn't seem to work. How can I achieve the desired effect ?

Comment: Perhaps send [SIGHUP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227774/difference-between-closing-the-terminal-using-the-closing-button-and-ctrl-d), since you cannot send [EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024667/what-character-for-eof-and-end-program).

Comment: @ThomasDickey EOF is not a character, EOT however is actually on the list of ASCII characters, hex 04 value.  That's what I'm trying to send.  Heemayls answer there isn't accurate, I think.

Comment: Maybe because you're in canonical mode so such bytes would be consumed by tty driver before it get send.

Comment: @炸鱼  OK, how do I check if I'm canonical mode ?

Comment: `stty -a` will dump the terminal settings for the current terminal. In the flags portion you will see `icanon`, the canonical flag. If this flag is preceded by an `-` then it is off, no dash then its on.

Comment: sending 4 over the `TIOCSTI` `ioctl` will nuke a terminal, not sure how that differs from what you're trying. for a shell like ZSH with `ignoreeof` set you may need to send a bunch of 4 with that `ioctl`

Answer (score 8):

First of all, a tty, even if it appears a single file object, is actually a pair of pipes/queues -- one for the output and one for the input, the other ends of each being connected either to the TX/RX of some hardware device, or made available to another program in the case of a pseudo-tty. When you're writing anything to the fd linked to a tty, you're writing into the *output* queue, even if that's the fd 0 (stdin) of your process, and will not be looped back into the *input* queue.

On most Unix systems (with the notable exception of [OpenBSD](https://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article;sid=20170701132619)), there's a special ioctl (`TIOCSTI`) which allows you to insert a byte into the input queue of a tty, as if it were received from the other end. `TIOCSTI` will only work as root when not used on the controlling tty of the process calling it.

```
$ cc -Wall tiocsti.c -o tiocsti
```

-- as root --

```
# printf '\04' | ./tiocsti >/proc/5460/fd/0
```

If your process is running in a pseudo-tty, another way to "fake" input is to connect with a debugger to the process holding the master side of the pseudo-tty, and `write(2)` your stuff into it from there.

```
$ gdb -p pid_of_xterm
(gdb) p write(4, "\x04", 1)   # 4 is the fd of the master pty
(gdb) c
```

Both methods are just **overkill**. If you want to control a running process, you better attach with a debugger to that very process instead of faking it some input; if you want to instrumentalize an interactive program, you better run it in [`expect`](http://core.tcl.tk/expect/index); both will work on any Unix system and don't require extra privileges for that.

Also notice that `^D` / `\004` will only work as `EOF` if **a)** the tty is in canonical mode **b**) the `c_cc[VEOF]` special character wasn't changed to something else **c**) the output queue is empty (otherwise `c_cc[VEOF]` will have to be sent twice). And of course, it will be the process which is just reading from tty which will get the EOF or those bytes, not necessarily the shell.

**tiocsti.c**

```c
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(void){
        char c; ssize_t r;
        while((r = read(0, &c, 1)) > 0){
                if(ioctl(1, TIOCSTI, &c)) err(1, "ioctl(TIOCSTI)");
        }
        if(r < 0) err(1, "read");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/566093/5132 has the restrictions and non-portability notes.