# Can a process send keystrokes or read text to/from a tty that is running su/sudo?

Tags: sudo, tty, su, vulnerability

I need some information regarding the possible attack vector on *nix platforms of running `su`/`sudo`.

Can an malicious process wait for the user to run `su` or `sudo` and then exploit that root access somehow? Or is this already protected somehow?

For example, if /dev/tty2 has impersonated `root` with `su`:

```bsh
# inject text 
echo Adding malicious text to a root tty, like Enter Password: > /dev/tty2
# read keystrokes
cat /dev/tty2 
# not sure how to write keystrokes or if it is possible
```

Maybe this is absolutely documented, or protected, if so, please link me the docs.

[image: example]

PS: Please don't shut me down as if I am requesting help to do an exploit. I am not. The question is about the risks of using `su`/`sudo` versus logging as `root` in the context of a [discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1032#issuecomment-575001432) about whether should Windows have a `sudo` command or not. I need to get my facts straight.

Comment: You're asking about the security model of one set of operating systems, the set that is on topic here and fine to ask about.  But you're doing so in order to then go and use that as an argument about a different operating system, not on topic here, with a _different security model by design_.  Your best bet is to go and learn about the _Windows_ security model.  Start by learning about the Shatter Attack, and why the Windows world is strongly averse to bringing that back _irrespective_ of what weaknesses there might be in Unices and Linux.  Here really isn't the place for that.

Comment: @JdeBP Your questioning of Gerardo's intentions and recommendation of investigating a different topic is inappropriate to the question/answer rules of Stack Exchange.  Gerardo is asking a very concrete question on *nix security and this is the proper place to do that.  What this site is not is a place for pointless controversy.
His clarification and mention of Windows is just to explain that he's not doing research for a malicious purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a process can inject input into a tty via the [`TIOCSTI`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493684/308316) ioctl. At least on Linux, that's subject to some [restrictions](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/tty/tty_io.c?id=5b21115414f5b5220e7ab3ca7f5d2c1396f11854#n2168): the user should be root (`CAP_SYS_ADMIN`) **or** inject into its *controlling tty*.

That's still quite dangerous, and `TIOCSTI` was [gutted](https://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article;sid=20170701132619) in systems like OpenBSD, but its threat model was usually backwards than that from your question: the root was supposed to use `su` (or something else) to run a command as an ordinary user, and that command was able to insert keys into the controlling tty it was sharing with its privileged caller. See examples [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=173008) and [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=628843).

Of course, that could also be exploited via a `biff(1)` or some other program running in the same tty `su root` was started from, but that's doesn't look that interesting: if an attacker was able to get grip of an account able to `su` or `sudo`, there are probably simpler an nicer ways to escalate it.