# Simulating an input from ttyS0 in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port

I work with cash registers that are bare-boned RedHat Linux boxes. These registers have a scanner attached to a serial port (`ttyS0`).

We do a lot of testing that requires someone to stand at the register and swipe products across the scanner. I'm trying to figure out a way to remove the person from the equation.

Is there an easy way to simulate input FROM the serial port?

Obviously, sending information TO the serial port is easy:

```bsh
echo [whatever] > /dev/ttyS0
```

but what I'd really love is some sort of bash code where I could type:

```bsh
echo [barcode number] > (some code that makes the machine think the barcode number is coming from the serial port)
```

Is this possible?

I'm also restricted in what I can actually put on the register. I can't install any new utilities onto the machine. I can put `bash` scripts on there, but that's about it.

Comment: Can the software work with any character device? If yes, then you could use a simple named pipe (mkfifo) instead of ttyS0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that (as root) with the `TIOCSTI` ioctl. See the example program at the end of this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493684/308316). Use it as

```
echo [whatever] | ./tiocsti > /dev/ttyS0
```

You can also do that from perl without having to compile anything -- search this site, there are plenty of [examples](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=perl+TIOCSTI).

Another option that *I* am using, is doing it in hardware: simply connect the machine to itself via an USB->serial adapter, and write to the `/dev/ttyUSBx` (or `/dev/serial/by-id/xx-xx-xx`) whatever you want read from `/dev/ttySx` (make `/dev/ttyUSBx` raw with `stty raw` so it does pass the data unchanged).

Comment: I tried it, but it give an error " bash: ./tiocsti: No such file or directory
bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe
"

Comment: `tiocsti` is supposed to be the program you compiled via `cc tiocsti.c -o tiocsti`. But I strongly recommend the "serial loopback" solution, because that will allow you to test it in the same environment as in the production. __And BTW__: why have you the `SIGPIPE` ignored in your shell? `echo` to a broken pipe should be killed silently, not print `"write error: Broken pipe"`.

Comment: what is seriial loopback solution?

Comment: To use a USB->serial adapter to connect your machine to itself, as described in the answer. Notice that you could compile that `tiocsti.c` program on another machine and copy it to your bare-bones machine; it's self contained and only depends on the C library.

Comment: Oh, you mean connect my machine to itself using a USB adapter! And how do I compile the tiocsti.c code, do I need to compile it using dev? Sorry I am a total novice, need to learn more

Comment: Yes, you need a compiler and the libc development packages (eg. `dnf install gcc glibc-devel`, `apt-get install gcc libc6-dev` or similar on a distro which is not newer than that where the program should run).

Comment: I try the serial loopback solution and gladly I can re-read the data that I sent .I tried something like `cat "123456789101112\n\r > dev\USBx` and  able to read it back in another terminal using `cat \dev\ttyS0` . However my Java GUI doesn't respond to it. My Java GUI has already been programmed to read barcode input from ttyS0 serial port .  What is the correct string that is normally sent by an RS232 barcode scanner into PC Serial Port?

Comment: Thank you very much, finally got it to works using TIOCSTI method!

Answer (score 7):

`TIOCSTI` is available, but that's not a highly regarded mechanism nowadays.  An alternative is very simple: this is what pseudo-terminals do.  Just point the scanner at a pseudo-terminal instead of the real serial terminal, and drive the appropriate input from the pseudo-terminal's master side.  Indeed, [`expect`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index) comes ready-made for driving an interactive terminal I/O application via a pseudo-terminal.

It all depends from whether `expect`, which is in a Fedora package, is one of the things that the people who installed everything chose to have already installed on your machine.  That's also true of Perl, of course.  We answerers have no way of knowing what the vague "bare boned" actually entails.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I am able to solve it. Thank you very much guys.

1. Create a blank text file
2. Edit the file and copy and paste this code into the text file

```
//**tiocsti.c**//

#include <unistd.h>`
#include <err.h>

int main(void)
{
            char c; ssize_t r;
    while((r = read(0, &c, 1)) > 0)
    {
                    if(ioctl(1, TIOCSTI, &c)) 
        {   
            err(1, "ioctl(TIOCSTI)");
        }       
    }   
        if(r < 0)
    err(1, "read");
            return 0;
}
```

3. Save the text file as `tiocsti.c`
4. On the same directory, run `cc tiocsti.c -o tiocsti` on your terminal to compile the  tiocsti.c file you created in the first step

5.To generate fake input into ttyS0, simply run

`echo yadayada  | ./tiocsti > /dev/ttyS0`