# Bash: echo command into tty

Tags: bash, tty, echo, python3, stdin

I've a service written in Python that can receive commands and does things, here is how it is built:

```
    print("\nWelcome!\n")

    for line in sys.stdin:
        cmd=line.rstrip()
        if cmd == "ls" or cmd == "help":
            print("Available Commands:")
```

Now this service is started with `systemd` and its unit file has the following:

```
[Service]
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ExecStart=...service.py
WorkingDirectory=...

StandardOutput=tty
StandardInput=tty-force
TTYVHangup=yes
TTYPath=/dev/tty60
TTYReset=yes
```

So the service input and output is attached to the `tty60`. I can use `conspy 60` to see what the service is doing and interact with it. For instance here I typed `test` and then `help`:

```
test
Error: command 'test' not found.
Type 'help' for a list of available commands.

help
Avaliable Commands:
> status, fan1, fan2, fan3, fan4, wake, sleep, quit
```

Python is able to grab what I typed and answers as expected.

**Now, how can I send a command to the `tty` without entering an interactive program like `conspy`?**

I tired `echo -e "ls\n" >> /dev/tty60` and in another terminal with `conspy` I can see the command but Python didn't process it:

```
help **---> sent via conspy**
Avaliable Commands:
> status, fan1, fan2, fan3, fan4, wake, sleep, quit
help **---> sent with "echo"**
```

As you can see the last `help` sent via `echo` wasn't processed.

Thank you.

Comment: The usual way to receive commands is to create a listening socket, not to hijack a tty device. It works, but it's not really "best practice"

Comment: Yeah but I need to be able to interact with it directly via a tty / cli but also have a script sending commands on timers etc.

Comment: Yes, sending _output_ to a tty does not nagicially make it _input_ from that tty. On Linux (and some other Unices but not all) to fake tty input use ioctl(fd,TIOCSTI,ptr) [like conspy does](https://sourceforge.net/p/conspy/code/ci/default/tree/conspy.c#l811); putting TIOCSTI in the search box at the top of this page finds dozens more examples.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I ended up going with https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570854/23085. Thank you for the explanation of the issue, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.