How do I redirect END OF TRANSMISSION itself to another terminal?
I'm playing around with sending information to another terminal session remotely, but I'm not sure how to signal the end of a transmission (ie so the other terminal session stops awaiting input).
For example:
# terminal 1
$ echo $TTY > ~/mytty
$ read

# terminal 2
$ othertty=$(cat ~/mytty)
$ echo hello > $othertty
$ echo "goodbye\n\r\04" > $othertty

# terminal 1 (again)
hello
goodbye


[still awaiting input]

How do I send an end of transmission signal? I've tried various methods of sending 0x04, which I believe is the ascii character indicated by CTRL-D, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I don't know if it's because I'm not signaling the control character correctly, or whether it's that I'm signaling it correctly, but that terminal 2 (in above example) is interpreting the characters itself, rather than passing them along to terminal 1 so that terminal 1 stops reading.
Any help or pointers in the right direction is appreciated!

Output to a terminal is not input from that terminal. You did send the "control-D" code with echo \04 (given a shell or system where echo handles escape sequences; not all do) but it doesn't display anything (because it's a control character) and it has no effect on the read command that is waiting for input -- because output is not input. If you want to provide input to some other tty, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696106/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493578/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570507/

This question is similar to: How to send ^D / EOT character to stdin of a shell process?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
