# How to follow-up a command with Ctrl + D (EOF)

Tags: linux, command-line, exit

I would like to run a few commands and give an explicit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, just like, say:

```
ls;pwd;^D
```

Unfortunately, the above doesn't work. I've also tried `\04` and `0x4` in place of `^D` above as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110240/why-does-ctrl-d-eof-exit-the-shell). These too don't work. How can I achieve this? Also, how is this different from:

```
ls;pwd;exit
```

Comment: Note that if you type `ls;pwd;` followed by `Ctrl-D` (instead of `Enter`), nothing special happens. Do you want to exit the shell after running those commands?

Answer (score 2):

It's partially explained [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110248/70524), so I'll try to quote the relevant parts:

> Now, if the current line was empty, and provided the application will
>   have fully read the previously entered lines, the `read` will return 0
>   character.
>
> That signifies *end of file* to the application (when you read from a
>   file, you read until there's nothing more to be read). That's why it's
>   called the `eof` character, because sending it causes the application
>   to see that no more input is available.
>
> Now, modern shells, at their prompt do not set the terminal in
>   `icanon` mode because they implement their own *line editor* which is
>   much more advanced than the terminal driver built-in one. However, in
>   their own *line editor*, to avoid confusing the users, they give the
>   `^D` character (or whatever the terminal's `eof` setting is with some)
>   the same meaning (to signify `eof`).

That last line can use a bit more clarification. From [the documentation of Bash's line editor, readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-end_002dof_002dfile-_0028usually-C_002dd_0029):

> **`end-of-file` (usually C-d)**
>   The character indicating end-of-file as set, for example, by `stty`.
>   If this character is read when there are no characters on the line,
>   and point is at the beginning of the line, Readline interprets it as
>   the end of input and returns EOF.

Hence, for readline (and also for most other shells), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> is only EOF at the start of a line. So, even if you did manage to add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> at the end of that line, it won't be treated as EOF.

And whether EOF will make your interactive shell exit is also a different problem. For bash, this is governed by the `IGNOREEOF` variable and the `set -o ignoreeof` option. The [variable's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-IGNOREEOF) says:

> Controls the action of the shell on receipt of an EOF character as the
>   sole input. If set, the value denotes the number of consecutive EOF
>   characters that can be read as the first character on an input line
>   before the shell will exit. If the variable exists but does not have a
>   numeric value, or has no value, then the default is 10. If the
>   variable does not exist, then EOF signifies the end of input to the
>   shell. This is only in effect for interactive shells.

Example:

```
bash-5.0$ IGNOREEOF=
bash-5.0$ <Ctrl-D> Use "exit" to leave the shell.
bash-5.0$ <Ctrl-D> Use "exit" to leave the shell.
bash-5.0$ <Ctrl-D> Use "exit" to leave the shell.
bash-5.0$
```

Do it 7 more times and it will finally exit.

---

I don't really see any use for this. If you want to exit the shell at the end of these commands, just use `exit`.